# Add custom property to vtkXMLUnstructuredGrid using python

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, paraview

I have a .vtu file representing a mesh which I read through vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader. Then I create a numpy array (nbOfPoints x 3) in which I store the mesh vertex coordinates, which I'll call meshArray.
I also have a column array (nOfPoints x 1), which I'll call brightnessArray, which represents a certain property I want to assign to the vertexes of the meshArray; so to each vertex corresponds a scalar value. For example: to the element meshArray[0] will correspond brightnessArray[0] and so on.
How can I do this?

It is then possible to interpolate the value at the vertexes of the mesh to obtain a smooth variation of the property I had set in order to visualize it in paraview?

Thank you.
Simon

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you precise what are your inputs and what output is desired.

Comment: My inputs are the vtu mesh and an array. The mesh has a certain number of nodes (nbOfPoints), and the array is of the same length. The mesh is an XMLUnstructuredGrid. Each node can contain information on a certain property. For example a velocity field could be represented by scalar values assigned the mesh nodes. The desired output is a new mesh, with the same points of the original one, to which the array values have been assigned. In other words, I want to arbitrarily assign a new scalar field to the mesh. 
This is complicated to explain, sorry. I hope I was more clear this time.
Thanks.

Comment: much clearer. This should be doable with a python programmable filter. Where is stored the array ?

Comment: I'm not sure on what you mean by 'where the array is stored'. It is a numpy array which I create from a file based on a code I wrote. I then store it as a .npy file.

Comment: Are you able to read this array into ParaView, if so with which reader ? Unless you want to read it directly with numpy ?

Comment: I do read it with numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do :

1. Write a Python Programmable Source to read your numpy data as a vtkUnstructuredGrid. 
   Here are a few examples of programmable sources :
   https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Simple_ParaView_3_Python_Filters
   https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter
2. Read your .vtu dataset
3. Use a "Ressample with Dataset" filter on your python programmable source output and select your dataset as "source"

And you're done.

The hardest part is writing the programmble source script.